# Convergence of a normalized density weighted sum in the limit

Tags: expected-value, convergence

Let $X \sim f_X$ and assume that for each $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we have datasets of $N$ iid samples $D_N = \{ X_i | 1 \leq i \leq  N \}$. Also assume that there is some bounded deterministic function $g(X) \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm wondering what could be said about the limit:

$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N} f_X(X_i) \right)^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N} g(X_i)f_X(X_i)$

My intuition is that being a convex sum it should not diverge, but does it converge to the expected value of $g(X)$? If it does, are there any conditions or assumptions required on $g(\cdot)$ or $f_X$? If it doesn't could you explain why? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $f(X)$ and $g(X)f(X)$ are integrable with $\mathbb E_X[f(X)]\ne0 $, it follows from the strong law of large numbers and the continuous mapping theorem that, almost surely,
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac1N \sum_{i=1}^{N} f(X_i) \right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\mathbb E_X[f(X)]}  $$
and
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^{N} g(X_i)f(X_i) = \mathbb E_X[g(X)f(X)] $$

Therefore
$$
\begin{align}\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N} f(X_i) \right)^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N} g(X_i)f(X_i) &= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac1N\sum_{i=1}^{N} f(X_i) \right)^{-1} \frac1N\sum_{i=1}^{N} g(X_i)f(X_i) \\
&= \frac{\mathbb E_X[g(X)f(X)]}{\mathbb E_X[f(X)]}
\end{align}
 $$
Furthermore, if $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are uncorrelated, the result can further be simplified to
$$\frac{\mathbb E_X[g(X)f(X)]}{\mathbb E_X[f(X)]} = \frac{\mathbb E_X[g(X)]\mathbb E_X[f(X)]}{\mathbb E_X[f(X)]}=\mathbb E_X[g(X)] $$